# panda expand columns with list into multiple columns

Tags: pandas

I want to expand / cast a column that contains lists into multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[[11,22],[33,44]]})
# I want:
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b1':[11,33], 'b2':[22,44]})
```

Comment: perhaps you could apply `b1, b2 = zip(*[[11,22],[33,44]])` on your `b` key values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[[11,22],[33,44]]})

df["b1"] = df["b"].apply(lambda cell: cell[0])
df["b2"] = df["b"].apply(lambda cell: cell[1])
df[["a", "b1", "b2"]]
```

Comment: I like this option best as it makes it easier to transfer to other cases

Answer (score 5):

Send the column `.tolist` and create the DataFrame, then join back to the other column(s).

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns='b'), pd.DataFrame(df['b'].tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix('b')], 
               axis=1)

   a  b0  b1
0  1  11  22
1  2  33  44
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.tolist()` on your `"b"` column to expand it out, then just assign it back to the dataframe and get rid of your original `"b"` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':[[11,22],[33,44]]})
df[["b1", "b2"]] = df["b"].tolist()

df = df.drop("b", axis=1) # alternatively: del df["b"]

print(df)
   a  b1  b2
0  1  11  22
1  2  33  44
```