# Pandas dataframe: select list items in a column, then transform string on the items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One of the columns I'm importing into my dataframe is structured as a list. I need to pick out certain values from said list, transform the value and add it to one of two new columns in the dataframe. Before:

| Name | Listed_Items |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | ["dr_md_coca_cola", "dr_od_water", "potatoes", "grass", "ot_other_stuff"] |
| Steve | ["dr_od_orange_juice", "potatoes", "grass", "ot_other_stuff", "dr_md_pepsi"] |
| Phil | ["dr_md_dr_pepper", "potatoes", "grass", "dr_od_coffee","ot_other_stuff"] |

From what I've read I can turn the column into a list

```py
df["listed_items"] = df["listed_items"].apply(eval)
```

But then I cannot see how to find any list items that start *dr_md*, extract the item, remove the starting *dr_md*, replace any underscores, capitalize the first letter and add that to a new *MD* column in the row. Then same again for *dr_od*. There is only one item in the list that starts *dr_md* and *dr_od* in each row. Desired output

| Name | MD | OD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Coca Cola | Water |
| Steve | Pepsi | Orange Juice |
| Phil | Dr Pepper | Coffee |

Comment: "One of the columns I'm importing into my dataframe" from where? Because most of the time, for a problem like this it's "easier" to clean your data BEFORE importing into a dataframe.

Comment: Thanks @Drakax, short answer is I don't have the opportunity to clean the data before.

Longer answer is I'm scripting a python visual that will be part of a power Bi dashboard. The values are coming from a database query into power bi. I could try to clean the data in SQL or Power Query, but I have more experience of text cleaning in python (wihtout pandas).

Comment: re: pre-processing and keeping track of SQL queries, I would strongly recommend using dbt (https://www.getdbt.com/) for version controlling your dashboard queries, it's a really phenomenal tool. You can run it on the cloud if you want, but I usually just stand up the package with a cron job on whatever server hosts the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is make a function that does the processing for you that you can pass into `apply` (or in this case, `map`). Alternatively, you could expand your list column into multiple columns and then process them afterwards, but that will only work if your lists are always in the same order (see [panda expand columns with list into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64702112/panda-expand-columns-with-list-into-multiple-columns)). Because you only have one input column, you could use `map` instead of `apply`.

```
def process_dr_md(l:list):
    for s in l:
        if s.startswith("dr_md_"):
            # You can process your string further here
            return l[6:]

def process_dr_od(l:list):
    for s in l:
        if s.startswith("dr_od_"):
            # You can process your string further here
            return l[6:]

df["listed_items"] = df["listed_items"].map(eval)
df["MD"] = df["listed_items"].map(process_dr_md)
df["OD"] = df["listed_items"].map(process_dr_od)
```

I hope that gets you on your way!

Comment: just don't forget to chage `l.startswith` to `s.startswith`, then :p

Comment: @Nathan, it needs updating in the return statement too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot_table`

```
df = df.explode('Listed_Items')
df = df[df.Listed_Items.str.contains('dr_')]

df['Type'] = df['Listed_Items'].str.contains('dr_md').map({True: 'MD', 
                                                           False: 'OD'})

df.pivot_table(values='Listed_Items', 
               columns='Type', 
               index='Name',
               aggfunc='first')
```

---

```
Type                MD                  OD
Name                                      
Phil   dr_md_dr_pepper        dr_od_coffee
Steve      dr_md_pepsi  dr_od_orange_juice
Tom    dr_md_coca_cola         dr_od_water
```

From here it's just a matter of beautifying your dataset as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach from the previous answers.
given a df of form:

```
    Name    Items
0   Tom [dr_md_coca_cola, dr_od_water, potatoes, grass...
1   Steve   [dr_od_orange_juice, potatoes, grass, ot_other...
2   Phil    [dr_md_dr_pepper, potatoes, grass, dr_od_coffe...
```

and making the following assumptions:

1. only one item in a list matches the target mask
2. the target mask always appears at the start of the entry string

I created the following function to parse the list:

```
import re
def parse_Items(tgt_mask: str, itmList: list) -> str:
    p = re.compile(tgt_mask)
    for itm in itmList:
        if p.match(itm):
            return itm[p.search(itm).span()[1]:].replace('_', ' ')
```

Then you can modify your original data farme by use of the following:

```
df['MD'] = [parse_Items('dr_md_', x) for x in df['Items'].to_list()]
df['OD'] = [parse_Items('dr_od_', x) for x in df['Items'].to_list()]
df.pop('Items')
```

This produces the following:

```
    Name    MD          OD
0   Tom     coca cola   water
1   Steve   pepsi       orange juice
2   Phil    dr pepper   coffee
```

Answer (score 0):

I would normalize de data before to put in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple


def clean_stuff(text: str):
    clean_text = text[6:].replace('_', ' ')
    return " ".join([
        word.capitalize()
        for word in clean_text.split(" ")
    ])


def get_md_od(stuffs: List[str]) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    md_od = [s for s in stuffs if s.startswith(('dr_md', 'dr_od'))]
    md_od = sorted(md_od)
    print(md_od)

    return clean_stuff(md_od[0]), clean_stuff(md_od[1])


dirty_stuffs = [{'Name': 'Tom',
                 'Listed_Items': ["dr_md_coca_cola",
                                  "dr_od_water",
                                  "potatoes",
                                  "grass",
                                  "ot_other_stuff"]},
                {'Name': 'Tom',
                 'Listed_Items': ["dr_md_coca_cola",
                                  "dr_od_water",
                                  "potatoes",
                                  "grass",
                                  "ot_other_stuff"]}
                ]

normalized_stuff: List[Dict[str, str]] = []
for stuff in dirty_stuffs:
    md, od = get_md_od(stuff['Listed_Items'])
    normalized_stuff.append({
        'Name': stuff['Name'],
        'MD': md,
        'OD': od,
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(normalized_stuff)
print(df)
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.